# Modifying CTFd database

Tags: mariadb, innodb

I'm trying to automate CTFd deployment using terraform and aws. My problem is that i'm trying to modify the default db of CTFd so i don't have to create the event and admin user manually and instead have it already created when i deploy my instance.

I need to know how to modify the CTFd db or if you have any other suggestions to solve my problem.

CTFd uses mariadb with innodb if i'm not mistaken.

I'm still trying to look at ressources about how to do this but i'm not on point on my db knowledge